# Two activities generate two activities? (Network diagram)

Tags: critical-path

[image]

Hi folks, I have a question regarding to the following table.
So I am required to draw a network diagram and a critical path.
However, I don't know how I should draw from C,D to G,H and also how I can draw J,K,L from two dependent activities. I am not sure how many lines should I draw. I am so confused. Please help.

Comment: You need to start graphing it You can have more than one edge per node in a critical path diagram, so map it out and see what connects where.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this. You should start drawing the network diagram according to the above table and see for yourself. True there are few conflicts with lines crossing each other, but that's not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to give it a real life situation and it will make sense to you. When you make dinner, it's ready at 7:00. One person may use your output at 7:10, and another person at 7:30, the second person having been busy doing something else. In other words, your output serves two people that need food, but these two people are a singer and drummer who need to work together and record a song for another person. Please note that in the first case, the 7:10 person got 20 minutes to rest. The 7:30 person will delay the process... find the path with no "rest" and this is your critical path